# How to set the Environment variable in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-test

facing an issue when the code is trying to access the System.getProperty() in Spring Test cases. working when setting the VM argument on the test case that is running, but to run each test case class, have to set the VM argument explicitly.

Is there a way to set the environment variables in the Spring before the application context loads.

Thanks in advance

Comment: try putting `System.setProperty(..)` in a static block in test class

Comment: @pvpkiran, thanks it worked for me

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `System.getProperty()`.

Rather, use Spring's `Enviornment` abstraction with *property sources* (e.g., `@PropertySource`) and `@Value("${propertyName}")` to inject the value of the property into your production components (e.g., `@Service` classes, etc.).

Then, in your integration tests annotated with `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)`, use `@TestPropertySource` to override production property values with test property values.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the help of a static block, which is executed in the first place before anything else

```
static {
    System.setProperty("", "");
  }
```